# Zend Form Displays weird chars on non-english chars

Tags: php, character-encoding, zend-form

I use UTF-8  everywhere on the site, the data come back in UTF-8 too, it works everywhere on the page, except one case: the (zend) form value.

I have checked everything, the string is utf-8, the page encoding is utf-8, the result from the Api is utf8.

> ```
> (Margar\u00e9t\u00e1\u00f3\u0171\u00fa\u0151\u00fc\u00f6)
> ```

This  is  what I see in the divs, as well as  in the header too :

```
Margarétáóűúőüö
```

This is what I got in the form:

```
MargarÃ©tÃ¡Ã³Å±ÃºÅ‘Ã¼Ã¶
```

I have tried many things, `utf8_encode` , `mb_convert_encoding` , but nothing was happened.

I used a helper, the $name contains the 'Margarétáóűúőüö' value:

```
    $form = $this->_helper->form('user-settings');
    $form->addElement('text', 'name', array(
            'label'      => 'Name',
            'value'         => $name,
            'required'   => true,
            'autocapitalize' => 'off',
            'autocorrect' => 'off',
        ));
```

Comment: CAn you show what you're using to display the form?

Comment: By the way, what you have there is UTF-8 data being displayed as windows-1252 (an ISO-8859-1 variant): http://codepad.viper-7.com/ehrv5Q So either you're displaying the original UTF-8 data as ISO-8859-1 or you're displaying as UTF-8 but the data underwent a conversion from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 even though the original data was not in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: It just happening with the forms , in the label as well as in the elements too. It looks like it's double encoded.

Comment: It seems it just happen when I use the Zend form helper, instead of the zend form. Nee more time to investigate.

Comment: Please post the fragment of your code where you obtain the value that is wrong for your (the part "this is what I got in the form"), so it's more clear at which point you're concerned.

Comment: Did you try iconv? It helped me many times in the past. Are you using a database? For example you have to do this in mysql: SET NAMES "UTF8"

Comment: Yes , I have tried. No, I don't use a  database, I use REST API. Yes, I have tried the iconv too.

Comment: Using an external form  $form = new Form_UserSettingsForm(array('user'=>$user)); maybe resolve the problem.However, passing variables can case "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in " error sometimes.

Comment: Ok , it just happening when I try to use this form using a partialAction, which uses a  DOM functionality. There is a saveHTML in it, and that function doesn't handle the utf-8 chars, that's why the result contains weird chars.

Comment: I suggest you should answer your own question if you have the problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized, that we used a  partialLoop + form helper  to get the a subform . Unfortunately , we used a DOM in it, and the the `saveHTML()` function in `DOM` is a  little bit buggy, don't handle the UTF-8 chars very well .

When I removed this subform and used the $form = new Form_UserSettingsForm($user); directly, it worked  well.

So be careful, when you use a $dom->saveHTML() function anywhere in your code!